# Clientaccesspolicy.xml randomly not being requested

Tags: wcf, silverlight

I have a silverlight 3 application running on a seperate domain that my WCF services.  Using both fiddler and Web Dev Helper I am able to see that when I make a web service call SOMETIMES a request is made to clientaccesspolicy.xml and everything works great.

The issue is that is doesnt always make this request.  When it doesnt, obviously my app creashes.

I am 3 days on this now.  I have investigated it being a timing issue (call made before xml policy loads), permission issue, caching issues, etc...  I am totally stuck.  There appears to be no rhyme or reason to it.

Some clients work, other dont.  Then the other work and new people stop working.  It is completely random.

Please help!

Thanks!
Jon

Comment: Like I asked over in the Silverlight Forums, is your client access file a static file? Are you using IIS? Anything else you can tell us about the application?

Comment: As asked in the Forums, are you certain that it is the client access policy that is the issue? Not a WCF configuration issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try this post for your answer:

[clientaccesspolicy.xml not requested the first time in some browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7847220/clientaccesspolicy-xml-not-requested-the-first-time-in-some-browsers)

are all of the sites in the same zone?